# Is that correct using of "this" keyword?

Tags: c#, this

I would like to know if I get it correctly: also with this keyword I can distinct between fields and variables?
Like this:

```
class X
{
  int x;
  public X(int x)
  {
    this.x=x;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hm, I might be a bit old fashioned in this point, but I always require the usage of the `m` prefix for fields of a class or struct.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, if a method parameter (or local variable) has the same name as a field, you *need* to use `this` to distinguish the two. Also, [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) is very vocal about every class member access being done through `this`, but whether that's a good idea or not may be up to debate. It makes things more clear, but also adds much visual clutter.

Comment: This is known as "shadowing" and it's not just StyleCop that is vocal about this =D (http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/variables/60shadow-variables.html)

Comment: @Hypnos: StyleCop complains about *every* use of a class member without `this` or `base`. Not just those where a local variable would shadow it. Agreed though, that it usually is poor practice to have a local variable shadow a class member, although for backing fields for properties and constructor arguments I guess it's mostly ok.